# Kubernetes Cluster-AutoScaler error: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a cluster Autoscaler for my kubernetes cluster and when I'm looking at the autoscaler logs im seeing these error messages:

```
1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: csidrivers.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler" cannot list resource "csidrivers" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
E0922 10:14:33.794709       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1beta1.CSIStorageCapacity: failed to list *v1beta1.CSIStorageCapacity: csistoragecapacities.storage.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler" cannot list resource "csistoragecapacities" in API group "storage.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
I0922 10:14:35.491641       1 reflector.go:255] Listing and watching *v1.Namespace from k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134
E0922 10:14:36.196200       1 reflector.go:138] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.Namespace: failed to list *v1.Namespace: namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-autoscaler" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope
```

Anyone might have a clue what might be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: feel free steve to add your solution as as answer or if below answer resolves your issue you can update the status mark one as a solution or post yours solution as answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just make sure **cluster-autoscaler** has permission to use the resource **csidrivers** you can edit the RBAC and add the access for `storage.k8s.io`

Edit cluster role with this

```
- apiGroups:
  - storage.k8s.io
  resources:
  - storageclasses
  - csinodes
  - csidrivers
  - csistoragecapacities
  verbs:
  - watch
  - list
  - get
```

Answer (score 0):

The RBACs for cluster-autoscaler is missing permissions for the resources mentioned in the error